# Security and efficiency for profile picture upload

Tags: php, security

I am trying to allow users to upload profile pics on my site. Basically I am following this code: [Allow users to upload a pic for their profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360568/allow-users-to-upload-a-pic-for-their-profile).

I don't know if the code is secure enough. I am worried that users may upload malicious files.

Also, I am concerned that if there is many users, I will have many pictures in a single folder and it may slow down the retrieving process. I wonder what is the best practice in storing the profile pics. How many photos maximum should there be in a folder for better efficiency?

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
{   
    uploadImage($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], 100, 100, "image/users/test2.jpeg");
}
```

and

```
function uploadImage($source, $max_width, $max_height, $destination) {

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($source);
if ($width > 150 || $height > 150) {
    $ratioh = $max_height / $height;
    $ratiow = $max_width / $width;
    $ratio = max($ratioh, $ratiow);
    // New dimensions
    $newwidth = intval($ratio * $width);
    $newheight = intval($ratio * $height);

    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

    $ext = trim(strtolower($_FILES['image']['type']));

    $sourceImage = null;

    // Generate source image depending on file type
    switch ($ext) {   
    case "image/jpg":
    case "image/jpeg":
        $sourceImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
        break;
    case "image/gif":
        $sourceImage = imagecreatefromgif($source);
        break;
    case "image/png":
        $sourceImage = imagecreatefrompng($source);
        break;
    }

    imagecopyresampled($newImage, $sourceImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    // Output file depending on type
    switch ($ext) {
    case "image/jpg":
    case "image/jpeg":
        imagejpeg($newImage, $destination);
        break;
    case "image/gif":
        imagegif($newImage, $destination);
        break;
    case "image/png":
        imagepng($newImage, $destination);
        break;
    }

    // Destroy resources
    imagedestroy($newImage);
    imagedestroy($sourceImage);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what happens if I upload a .exe file? or even a .txt file? Your application will give errors. Always have a fallback for if some hack0r uploads a non-picture to your application. Use the default: statement in your switch cases for that and hand back an error when they try to upload a non-image or a image you don't support (e.g. svg).

You talk about security and number of files in one directory, why is there a correlation between these two? The only restriction you have on the number of files per directory depends on the Filestructure format.

I would however create a directory per user instead of storing all the images in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

This won't help with security, but if you want to shorten your code a little, you can replace this

```
// Generate source image depending on file type
switch ($ext) {   
case "image/jpg":
case "image/jpeg":
    $sourceImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    break;
case "image/gif":
    $sourceImage = imagecreatefromgif($source);
    break;
case "image/png":
    $sourceImage = imagecreatefrompng($source);
    break;
}
```

with this

```
$sourceImage = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($source));
```

Also why don't you just store the whole lot as jpg, why is it necessary to save them as different types

Comment: Always make sure there is a default. Especially in a case like this where the program has a chance of breaking if the conditions aren't met.